# Как в string можно записать кавычки?

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, с таким еще не сталкивался.

Не получается записать строку в переменную стринг:

```
string a="tooo"uuuu"oooooo";
```

Компилятор понимает это как 2-е строки с uuuu в центре...

А как сделать, чтобы это была 1 строка?

Спасибо.

Comment: Обратные слеши перед апострофами `string a="tooo\"uuuu\"oooooo";`

Comment: Спасибо, выручили!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

string a="tooo\"uuuu\"oooooo";